# Use of :80 in proxy URL

Tags: http, tcp, squid, curl

Setting some Squid proxies up, and trying to figure out some behavior.

Squid in a pass-all configuration, with the linux node set to forward 80 to port 3128, which Squid is listening on.

I do have an AWS NLB in front of the proxy, however the same behavior occurs when I target the proxy via the dedicated host IP address.

How are:

```
curl -v --proxy http://my-proxy-pal.lab.my_domain.com:80 https://www.microsoft.com
```

and

```
curl -v --proxy http://my-proxy-pal.lab.my_domain.com https://www.microsoft.com
```

Not the same curl command? HTTP operates on tcp/80? When you do the :80 (or :3128), the request passes through, but if you omit it, the request fails.

I'm assuming that it has something to do with the behavior of http vs tcp, but I'm not 100% certain. So, anyone with some insight on that behavior, super appreciated on the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it as I started digging through the man pages of curl

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-x

```
If the port number is not specified in the proxy string, it is assumed to be 1080.
```